# Searching and finding word within string in C++/CLI

Tags: c++-cli

everyone.
I need your help. I am writing gui application in C++/CLI with VisualStudio 2017. I want to search and find a word within string.

Answer (score -1):

You're referring to managed String objects. SO this is just worth to google it.

```
String^ text = "I love apple";
bool result = text->Contains("apple");
```

Full documentation [here in the MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx)